# What is the difference between the various unistd.h under /usr/include in Linux?

Tags: c, linux

Under the /usr/include directory in Linux i entered the command:
find -type f -name unistd.h which gave the following output:

./unistd.h
./linux/unistd.h
./asm-generic/unistd.h
./bits/unistd.h
./asm/unistd.h
./sys/unistd.h

my question is, what is the purpose of each unistd.h, since there is only one definiton of that file in the single unix specification ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`linux/unistd.h` actually points to `asm/unistd.h`, which in turn points to either `asm/unistd_32.h` or `asm/unistd_64.h`, which is where system call numbers are defined and presented to user space depending on the system's architecture. These come from the kernel.

`bits/unistd.h` is a collection of macros that augment `unistd.h` (mostly stuff to help prevent buffer overflows), which is conditionally included via:

```
/* Define some macros helping to catch buffer overflows.  */
#if __USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL > 0 && defined __extern_always_inline
# include <bits/unistd.h>
#endif
```

In essence, the only POSIX required header is in fact, just `unistd.h`, the rest are either extensions, or definitions from the kernel. So, just including `unistd.h` is all you have to worry about doing, everything you need will be pulled in depending on your architecture and whatever build options you've selected.

Answer (score 5):

It's a common technique in C and C++ - you have a single file with the "standard" name in the "standard" place, in this case ./unistd.h, and then have that file include one or more implementation specific files, depending on preprocessor macros.  If you look at almost any "standard" C or C++ header files, you will see it including other files not mentioned in any standard.

Answer (score 0):

Basically think of `/usr/include/unistd.h` as a smart symbolic link.  It will point to a correct implementation depending on what your operating conditions are.

That said, it makes difficult sometimes to figure out what that correct implementation is.